# Accounting for non-linear trend in SOME samples of a linear mixed model using quadratic

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, predictor, quadratic-form

I have the following data: Pine Forest `Biomass ~ Age | Plot`:

[image]

<sup>Each black curve represents whole-plot biomass for each individual plot</sup>

I want to formally examine this trend using **mixed effects model** (using `lme4` function in R).

Thus far, I created a mixed model with random intercepts and slopes:

```
lme4(Biomass ~ I(Age - 51) + (1 + I(Age - 51) | Plot), data = dat, REML = F)
```

I added additional predictors to the model to better explain some of the trend:

```
lmer(Biomass ~ I(Age - 51) * LossRate + I(Age - 51) * I(scale(PineStems)) + (1 + I(Age - 51)|Plot),data = dat, REML = F)
```

- where `LossRate` is biomass lost per year due to mortality and `PineStems` are the number of pine stems in a given plot in a given year.

This model seems to perform just fine (based on significant 95% bootstrapped CIs for coefficient estimates and for CIs for the whole model). However, it **doesn't account for the downward curve** you can see in some plots.

I was thinking I could account for this curve by **incorporating a quadratic term for age** (i.e., `I(scale((Age - 51)^2))`  [we'll call it "`Age^2`"]

However, I'm not sure the best way to do this....

I'm pretty sure that I need to **add a random effect for `Age^2`** since only some plots have the curve, but **do I also need to add `Age^2` as a fixed effect?**

- Adding it as both a fixed and random effect improves the AIC of the model a lot (vs. no `Age^2` term), but adding just the random `Age^2` (without `Age^2` as a fixed effect) improves the model even more.
- In general, **does adding a squared "time" predictor as a random effect but not adding it as a fixed effect make sense??**  (read: "Can I do that??")

Further, I expect the largest impact of `PineStems` on the model as being the main driver causing the downward slope in biomass in mature plots. In other words, I mostly expect `PineStems` to drive the `Age^2` term (so that as `PineStems` decreases to a certain point, the trend line turns downward). How can I additionally add that to my model? Just simply by creating an interaction (`Age^2 * PineStems`)? Or does the model make this connection on its own?